# Printing out an int method with user input

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to do factorial methods in two different ways.  The first one is an iterative method which works great to print out.  I am having difficulty printing out the recursive method which is an int method instead of void.  How would I go about printing out the recursive method by using input the same as the iterative way?  Any help is much appreciated.  I am trying to just call each method in my main.

Java code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Factorial
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int fact = input.nextInt();

        //Call the iterative method
        int ifact = iFactorial(fact);
        System.out.println("The factorial iteratively is: " + ifact);
        //Call the recursive method
        int rfact = rFactorial(fact);
        System.out.println("The factorial recursively is: " + rfact);
    }

    //Iterative method starts
    public static int iFactorial(int fact)
    {

        for(int i = fact-1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            fact *= i;
        }
        return fact;
    }
    //Iterative method ends

    //Recursive method starts
    public static int rFactorial(int fact)
    {
        if(fact == 1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else 
        {
            return fact * rFactorial(fact-1);
        }
    }
    //Recursive method ends
}
```

Comment: A method is meant to do one thing. 

Do you think recursively calculating a factorial and also grabbing user input is one thing?

Comment: Ahhh, so what needs to happen is I need to have a method that gets the user input and stores it and then call that value in each of the methods?

Comment: @Shawn Yes. Get the user input in `main`, and pass the `int` into the other two functions as an argument. You'll need to do a tiny bit of refactoring, but nothing major.

Comment: Yes - that's a good start.  Try collecting your user input in a separate function, or just within your `main()` function.  Then call your factorial methods based on that after.

Comment: You're close, just remember your methods are returning a value, so catch it with something like this:

`int solution = iFactorial(fact);
System.out.println ("The Solution: " + solution);`

Comment: Your iFactorial is incorrect. Loop should be for(int i = fact; i > 0; i--)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I go about printing out the recursive method by using input
>   the same as the iterative way?

Using same way you can't do it. Enter number prompt will come again and again in recursive method. You need to make separate following three line in main method.

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
{
   System.out.println("Enter a number");
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   int fact = input.nextInt();
    //Call the iterative method
    iFactorial(fact);
    //Call the recursive method
    rFactorial(fact);
}
```

Comment: So I tried that idea and changed the method to int agruments.  I am not getting a response after I changed the code though.  It lets me enter a number and then terminates.  I updated my code if you don't mind taking a look.

Comment: And where do you print out the results? It's doing exactly what you asked, but you didn't ask it to show the results.

Comment: Thanks guys I'm pretty sure it's working now :).  About to update the code to show.  Thank you all for the help, it gave me a much better understand to calling methods.